# How do I animate changes one at a time in SwiftUI on a button tap?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a loop where I update a value that changes the view.
In this example I want the updates to happen one at a time so you see it ripple across the row, but they all happen at once.

```swift
struct AnimationQuestion: View {
   @State var colors = "⬛️⬜️".map { String($0) }
   @State var reversedColors = "⬜️⬛️".map { String($0) }

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Spacer()
         Button("Tap") {
            let temp = colors
            for i in 0 ..< colors.count {
               withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4.0)) {
                  colors[i] = reversedColors[i]
               }
            }
            reversedColors = temp
            
         }
         Spacer()

         HStack {
            ForEach(Array(colors.enumerated()), id: \.0) { index, color in
               Text(color).tag(index)
            }
         }
         Spacer()
      }
   }
}

struct QuestionPreview: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      AnimationQuestion()
   }
}
```

I expected these lines to perform the animation sequentially (visibly):

```swift
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4.0)) {
         colors[i] = reversedColors[i]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You identify by index `\.0`, but indices do not change after reversing, so refresh is instant, instead you need to identify by color value `\.1` (in this case they are unique).

Here is a fix

[image]

```
ForEach(Array(colors.enumerated()), id: \.1) { index, color in
   Text(color).tag(index)
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4